# Warning: Identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/master.pem not accessible: Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to connect another my instance in jenkins pipeline. And for test purpose create folder there.

```
stage('Deploying App to Kubernetes') {
      steps {
            script {
                sh "ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/master.pem ec2-user@52.15.183.121 /bin/bash"
                sh "mkdir /home/ec2-user/poker"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also opened permissions for my `master.pem` file by doing this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/master.pem
```

and still getting :

```
Warning: Identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/master.pem not accessible: Permission denied.
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: `$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Check by running these commands

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have given the pem key *too* much permissions.

Restrict the key so it can only accessed for the current user (on the ssh machine):

```
chmod 600 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/master.pem
```

---

Note: I can access the given IP, which should not be allowed. Either restrict the security group only to the needed CIDRs needed for access or try to use SSM to connect and execute commands on the server.